# Opening the default device browser from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, cordova

Hi I have some html content that I need to upload in a project I am building.

This content is build in another project using a WYSIWYG editor.

I decided to use an iFrame to load this content because my app has some global css resets that I do not want to apply to the content I receive and I am not able to determine 100% the style that are being applied to the HTML.

My problem is that I would like to open the links inside the iFrame outside of my app in the default device browser.

I usually did this so far by applying an event to the links which would do this:

window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');

But applying this inside the iFrame on the links only opens the content refered by the link inside the iframe.This would be no problem if some site's wouldn't have links with target="_blank".This links open the content on the phonegap window and on iOS devices I have no way of going back to my app.

So is there any way to open from inside the iFrame the default device browser?